# Passing a $scope value to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not sure if I am trying to do this the best (correct?) way but I have a word game in AngularJS page where players try to guess a word. Each letter is represented by a textbox and when a player enters their guess the letter is passed to a function which checks if the letter is correct and changes the colour of the box accordingly.

So far I have the following code in my partial file:

```
<p>Answer: {{selectedWord}}</p>

<div>
<input type="text" name="letters[]" class="answerbox" ng-repeat="guess in guesses" id="{{'letter_'+$index}}" ng-model="guess.value" onkeyup="testResults(this)" ng-focus="this.select();" size="1" maxlength="1">
</div>
```

This will take the input and pass it to my function which looks like this:

```
function testResults(letter) {
    var box_id = letter.id;

    var boxparts = box_id.split("_");
    var box_number = boxparts[1];

    var correct_answer = selectedWord(box_number-1, 1);
    var your_answer = letter.value;
    your_answer = your_answer.toLowerCase();

    if (your_answer == correct_answer) {
        letter.style.backgroundColor = "#32e53e";
    } else {letter.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6d6e"; }
                var is_correct = check_all();
    }
```

What I am unable to do is pass the value of the correct answer `($scope.selectedWord)` so that I can use it as the `var correct_answer` in my function.

I have tried simply passing it in with `onkeyup="testResults(this, $scope.selectedWord)"` and various alternatives but this is not working.

I would be greatful for some pointers as to how to pass this value into the function or if AngularJS offers a better way to achieve my aim.

Comment: try ng-keyup instead of onkeyup="testResults(this)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick hints:

- Always use angular directives (`ng-keyup`) instead of native javascript (`onkeyup`) to make your live easier.
- You can use `ng-repeat` to "iterate" a string on a template.
- Set your `ng-model` to an array, so you don't have to mess with ids and stuff. If you want to highlight the inputs in green or red, just use `ng-class`.

I made up a little fiddle for you as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ManuKaracho/fwp41qd2/

Comment: This works as is but could you please tell me how I might use this if my HTML file is a partial ? 
My controller is called Gamecontrol but if I simply change the div line to ng-controller="Gamecontrol as vm" I get a function undefined error. If I leave this out I do not get an error but no text boxes are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Angular way of keyup `ng-keyup="testResults(guess.value)"`